# I want to put an angular-gauge-chart in an angular. But there's an error. Is there a solution?

Tags: angular

Failed to compile.

C:/Users/LEE/Desktop/ims4/node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:\Users\LEE\Desktop\ims4\node_modules\ng2-charts\fesm2015'

Comment: Looks like issue of package module. Try to do npm instll

Comment: I don't know because it's my first time using an angular.What should I install?

Comment: and i try install @angular/core but remain the same

Comment: You need to run "npm install" command. This command will install all the dependencies you have mentioned in packge.json file. Make sure you have added "angular-gauge-chart" in your package.json file under dependencies. To add specific dependency you can run "npm install angular-gauge-chart" command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

1. remove folder node_modules
2. npm install
3. verify:

   import { GaugeChartModule } from 'angular-gauge-chart'

   imports: [
   GaugeChartModule,
   ]